# Find $a, b, c$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=2017$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, cubics

> Find all natural numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a\leq b\leq c$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=2017$.

### **My Attempt**

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=2017$$
$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)=2017*1$$
Now, $a+b+c$ can't be equal to $1$ as $a, b, c$ are natural numbers.
So, $$a+b+c=2017$$ $$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=1$$
How should I proceed after this?

Comment: Note that $$a^2+b^2+c2−ab−bc−ca^=\frac{((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2)}2$$

Comment: @miracle173 How did you notice that? Or: How can I notice things like that in other problems?

Comment: @SRobertJames Good question, but I don't remember and  I am not aware of a general method to notice such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=\frac{1}{2} \bigg( (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 \bigg)=1$$
$$ \implies (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 =2$$

So, two between $a,b,c$ are equal and the other has the difference of $1$ from the others.

WLOG, assume $b=a$ and $c=a \pm 1$ (Ignoring $a\le b\le c$ here.).

$$a+b+c=3a\pm1 = 2017 = 3\times672 \,+1$$

Thus $c=a+1$, $a=b=672$ and $c=673$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the Solution]

It was an easy question, just one important result and a bit of number theory was needed

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

These are surfaces over {a,b} expected reals. The calculations are straightforward.

[image]

The problems are the second and third solutions are complex. The graph shows only the real parts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Still calculations are straightforward.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of formulas here bur provide them as MathJax

Comment: Er, I'm in high school. This stuff is too complex for me.

Comment: I preferred to add some more solutions than rewriting the formulas in what is shown on [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5020/100). But thank You very much for the advice. I hope the solutions help.!